# Xpath in java for array of values

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following problem. Im using Xpath to extract the value from XML file using JAVA program

```
<place> 
<native name= "AAAAAA" />
<native name= "BBBBBB" />
<native name= "CCCCCC" />
<native name= "DDDDDD" />
<native name= "EEEEEE" />
</place>
```

Above is my partial XML file. Im using the following Xpath

```
/root/place/native/@name
/root/home
/root/xxxxxx
```

and i want my result to be like this

```
AAAAAA|BBBBBBB|CCCCCCC|DDDDDDD|EEEEEEEˆevergreenˆvaluesˆexample
```

How can i do this . Can any one help me

```
for (String temp : XpathValue) {
              TempFlat = xPath1.compile(temp).evaluate(xmlDocument);
                        TempFlat1 = TempFlat.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
                        value1.append(TempFlat1);
                        value1.append((char)"ˆ");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XPathExpression#evalute` will return a `NodeList` if you use `XPathConstants.NODESET`.

Once you have the `NodeList`, you will need to iterate the list and populate your array...

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xPath1.compile("/place/native[@name]").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
String[] results = new String[nodeList.getLength()];
for (int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(index);
    String name = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name");
    results[index] = name;
}
```

Comment: The problem is (from my testing), `evalute(xmlDocument)` is only return the first match, where as the example I posted returns all of them...

Comment: Okay , Can you kindly provide me the link to refer or more example

Comment: I added one more line (that gets the `NodeList` from the expession)

Comment: [How XPath Works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html), [XPath W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/). I've not read all the way through it, but this might be useful [Java XPath Tutorial: How To Parse XML File Using XPath In Java](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/)